# High Scores using NSUserDefaults not saving after app shut down

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I am really new to iOS programming and forgive me if I sound a bit ignorant but, whenever I try to save a high score within my app using `NSUserDefaults` I always lose it after the app is shut down.

This is in my `viewDidLoad` method:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:egtTopScr forKey:@"egtSectopScore"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
[prefs setInteger:egtTopScr forKey:@"egtSectopScore"];
```

This is what happens to the top score when the game ends:

```
if(scoreCounter > egtTopScr) {
    egtTopScr = scoreCounter;
}

topScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Best: %i", egtTopScr];
```

Comment: I can't see the code to fetch the values saved?

Comment: also save the latest score when the game ends. After your if condition.

Answer (score 0):

After the app launches you have to load the integer you saved.

```
NSInteger score = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"egtSectopScore"]
// do some stuff with score
```